# createStore with strict typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, strictnullchecks

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import * as storage from "redux-storage";

const reducer = storage.reducer((state, action) => ({}));

const store = createStore(reducer, {});
```

When using the above code with `strict` enabled for typescript, I am receiving the following warning:

```
[ts] Argument of type 'Reducer<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<{}, AnyAction>'.
       Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
         Type '{} | undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.
           Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.
```

I understand what TS strict mode is, but I don't understand why it interprets my state as potentially `undefined`

What could I be doing wrong? Or how could I deal with the error *without* doing something lazy like `as any`?

Comment: Just copied this into a new file and can't replicate this...

Comment: @George `"strict": true` in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score -1):

The state value provided can be undefined. Forcing it should fix your problem. E.g.

```
const reducer = storage.reducer((state = {}, action) => ({}));
```

Comment: Problem remains unchanged with your solution.